# Learning Logic, A Pathway

Tags: logic, reference-request

I would like to devote a greater amount of time to further learning logic. I have experience with mathematical proofs and thus have an understanding of logic to the degree necessary for proofs. I would like to go further and learn logic purely not necessarily restricted to that which is useful for math. I would like some insight and help in developing a self-study guide(topics and their order) of logic starting from the most fundamental and progressing from there. Is there a general pathway to follow in learning logic from scratch with the aim of gaining a deep understanding and overview of logic in its entirety? 
Thank you all(book recommendations are welcomed).

Comment: Take a look at Peter Smith's ["Teach yourself logic guide"](http://www.logicmatters.net/tyl/), where different textbook are cited and reviewed.

Comment: I would completely recommend Paul Whittaker's book 'Aristotle's de Interpretatione: Contradiction and Dialectic'. It is utterly astonishing how few philosophers understand the basics and this book covers them. Unless one falls into the hands of the Dialethists and other folk who cannot understand philosophy and feel that making it more complicated would be a solution you may need no more than this for a philosophical enquiry.  .

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Ha yeah I have the guide, I acquired it right before posting on here. I was a bit skeptical as to whether it was a sufficient or a proper guide. I am a bit cautious of not missing something in my self studying. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @PeterJ  Friends in that study philosophy have also made the recommendation. Thank you I will give the book a visit.

Answer (score 1):

***IEP, " Logical Consequence"*** ( online)

Stanford Encyclopedia, " First Order Logic" ( online)

Hardegree, Introduction to Logic ( https://courses.umass.edu/phil110-gmh/MAIN/IHome-5.htm)

Papineau, Philosophical Devices. ( For a first introduction to metalogical concepts).

***Nolt, Logics.***

---

Stoll, Set Theory And Logic. ( at archive.org)

***Enderton, Mathematical Introduction To Logic.***

Hunter, Metalogic.

***Van Dalen, Logic And Structure.***

---

Kleene, Introduction To Metamathematics.

PLUS  all the books of Raymond Smullyan

Comment: Thank you. I will give the books a visit.